# WCF not getting values from service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a service with method GetDetailByNo such that it takes id number as input parameter and gives personal details as output

```
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    DIT_DLH.DIT_WCFService.GetDetailByNoResponse DIT_DLH.DIT_WCFService.RequestDALPortType.GetDetailByNo(DIT_DLH.DIT_WCFService.GetDetailByNoRequest request) {
        return base.Channel.GetDetailByNo(request);
    }

    public object GetDetailByNo(long REQUESTID) {
        DIT_DLH.DIT_WCFService.GetDetailByNoRequest inValue = new DIT_DLH.DIT_WCFService.GetDetailByNoRequest();
        inValue.REQUESTID = REQUESTID;
        DIT_DLH.DIT_WCFService.GetDetailByNoResponse retVal = ((DIT_DLH.DIT_WCFService.RequestDALPortType)(this)).GetDetailByNo(inValue);
        return retVal.@return;
    }
```

GetDetailByNoRequest and GetDetailByNoResponse  are the classes in this service as follows:

```
public partial class GetDetailByNoRequest {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://dal.req.com", Order=0)]
    public long REQUESTID;

    public GetDetailByNoRequest() {
    }

    public GetDetailByNoRequest(long REQUESTID) {
        this.REQUESTID = REQUESTID;
    }
}

public partial class GetDetailByNoResponse {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://dal.req.com", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public object @return;

    public GetDetailByNoResponse() {
    }

    public GetDetailByNoResponse(object @return) {
        this.@return = @return;
    }
}
```

Now in my client code if i use

```
GetDetailByNoResponse retVal = new GetDetailByNoResponse();
retVal = (GetDetailByNoResponse)wcfClient.GetDetailByNo(12345678);
```

I get exception "Unable to convert System.Xml.XmlNode into GetDetailByNoResponse"
and if i do

```
XmlNode xmlnode = (XmlNode)wcfClient.GetDetailByNo(12345678);
```

or

```
Object obj=wcfClient.GetDetailByNo(12345678);
```

I do not get 
still i do not get personal details...

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: As such there is no error but the object which I receive from service does not contain values of personal details like name,age etc.